# Date missing in table after summarizing different column

Tags: r, date, dplyr, missing-data

Within RStudio, I have this code:

```
install(ggplot2)
install(dplyr)
Data is *gapminder_data.csv*

*str(gapminder_data.csv)*
'data.frame':   1704 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ country  : Factor w/ 142 levels "Afghanistan",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year     : int  1952 1957 1962 1967 1972 1977 1982 1987 1992 1997 ...
 $ pop      : num  8425333 9240934 10267083 11537966 13079460 ...
 $ continent: Factor w/ 5 levels "Africa","Americas",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ lifeExp  : num  28.8 30.3 32 34 36.1 ...
 $ gdpPercap: num  779 821 853 836 740 ...
```

When I execute the following code:

```
gapminder_data.csv  %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarize(min(gdpPercap), max(gdpPercap))
```

it works:

```
# A tibble: 142 x 3
   country     `min(gdpPercap)` `max(gdpPercap)`
   <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan             635.             978.
 2 Albania                1601.            5937.
 3 Algeria                2449.            6223.
 4 Angola                 2277.            5523.
 5 Argentina              5911.           12779.
 6 Australia             10040.           34435.
 7 Austria                6137.           36126.
 8 Bahrain                9867.           29796.
 9 Bangladesh              630.            1391.
10 Belgium                8343.           33693.
```

But, I miss the corresponding years for the values:

```
min(gdpPercap)   max(gdpPercap)
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't totally understand the question, since you haven't done anything that would identify corresponding years. You've phrased this as though the years with min and max GDP should be tracked, which they won't

Comment: When you group by and then summarize it removes the columns not being used by said group by and summarize. In this case since you did not include the years column in either your group or summarize, it removed them from your dataset.  I would try `gapminder_data.csv  %>% 
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  summarize(min(gdpPercap), max(gdpPercap)) `

Comment: @HanselPalencia , I don't think that's what OP wants - they want the value of the year where gdppercap is min/max. something like `year[gdpPercap==min(gdpPercap)` (though I'm not sure that would work within a summarize -- may require a separate `left_join`).

Comment: Hallo, Thanks to all for your rapid answer. If I add "year" in group_by - it was my first idea, too - the result is:1 Afghanistan  1952             779.             779.
 2 Afghanistan  1957             821.             821.
 3 Afghanistan  1962             853.             853.
 Etc... I want 1 min & 1 max per country. The year of these values are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give you what you need?

```r
mins <- gapminder_data.csv %>%
  arrange(gdpPercap) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
maxs <- gapminder_data.csv %>%
  arrange(desc(gdpPercap)) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()

left_join(
  select(mins, country, minyear=year, mingdp=gdpPercap), 
  select(maxs, country, maxyear=year, maxgdp=gdpPercap),
  by = "country")
# # A tibble: 142 x 5
#    country     minyear mingdp maxyear maxgdp
#    <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 Afghanistan    1997   635.    1982   978.
#  2 Albania        1952  1601.    2007  5937.
#  3 Algeria        1952  2449.    2007  6223.
#  4 Angola         1997  2277.    1967  5523.
#  5 Argentina      1952  5911.    2007 12779.
#  6 Australia      1952 10040.    2007 34435.
#  7 Austria        1952  6137.    2007 36126.
#  8 Bahrain        1952  9867.    2007 29796.
#  9 Bangladesh     1972   630.    2007  1391.
# 10 Belgium        1952  8343.    2007 33693.
# # ... with 132 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this pretty easily with a pivot. Since you didn't post a structure we could copy and paste (always helpful!), I've made a small sample tibble, but it should work on your larger set. After grouping by country, make a column to designate the max and min rows. We don't want the ones that aren't either, so drop those and finally spread the values to make a wide tibble with the max and min for each country. Generally, it's best to work in tidy (long-form) tibbles in R (what it is before the pivot), but you can easily get back there by using pivot_longer if need be.

```
tibble(
  country = rep("Afghanistan",4),
  year = seq(from = 1952, to = 1955),
  gdpPercap = c(779, 821, 853, 836)
) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(
    type = case_when(
      gdpPercap == max(gdpPercap) ~ "max",
      gdpPercap == min(gdpPercap) ~ "min"
    )
  ) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = country,
    names_from = type,
    values_from = c(year, gdpPercap)
  )
```

which produces:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   country [1]
  country     year_min year_max gdpPercap_min gdpPercap_max
  <chr>          <int>    <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Afghanistan     1952     1954           779           853
```

Comment: Hallo, GenesRus, your solution forces to select a priori a country, for example "Afghanistan". It is a partial solution. Thanks for the effort. Maerkli